# Cropping CALayer

Tags: ios, calayer

Given a CALayer, I am looking for a method to create two smaller CALayers (layerA & layerB) from a single CALayer (layerC).  layerA & layerB are subregions of layerC.  What's the best way to do this (best as in minimum memory usage and cpu time)?  Thanks.

Comment: It all depends on what kind of content your layers need to display. Do they display images?

Comment: yes, they are all images.  basically, I want to extract two regions of interest (layerA & layerB) from layerC.  Any idea how to do that?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to create layer A,B and create layer C for each and add it as sublayer to A,B.Now by using shape layer mask them to their required regions